# Unable to install shinytest in R

Tags: r

i am trying to install "shinytest" in R but not able to.
Below is the error message I am getting. Can anyone help me?
Not sure what the solution is.......

```
> install.packages("shinytest", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘D:/Windows/Analytics/XXXXXX/GitHub/XXXXX/XXXX/XXXX/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/shinytest_1.5.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 413601 bytes (403 KB)
downloaded 403 KB

package ‘shinytest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmchoJn\downloaded_packages
> library(shinytest)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shinytest’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘png’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘shinytest’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

I tried installing png as well. But no use

```
Installing package into ‘D:/Windows/Analytics/xxxx/GitHub/xxx/xxx/xxx/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
    binary source needs_compilation
png  0.1-7  0.1-8              TRUE

installing the source package ‘png’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/png_0.1-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24880 bytes (24 KB)
downloaded 24 KB

* installing *source* package 'png' ...
** package 'png' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
  checking PNG headers and libraries
./configure.win: line 11: E:/Program: No such file or directory
make: E:/Program: No such file or directory
make: E:/Program: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'E:/Program'.  Stop.
  LOCAL_SOFT does not exist, fall back to external png
  cannot find current PNG files
  attempting to download them
./configure.win: line 38: E:/Program: No such file or directory

 *** ERROR: unable to find PNG files

 They must be either in src/win32, in a tar-ball
 src/libpng-current-win.tar.gz or
 available via the LOCAL_SOFT R make setting.

 You can get the latest binary tar ball from
 http://www.rforge.net/png/files/

ERROR: configuration failed for package 'png'
* removing 'D:/Windows/Analytics/xxxx/GitHub/xxx/xxxx/xxx/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/png'

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmchoJn\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In utils::install.packages("png", dependencies = T) :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
```

Not sure what the solution is.
Should we install any dependencies?

Comment: See *"there is no package called ‘png’"*, try `install.packages("png")`.

Comment: I tried. See edited question

Comment: Try `install.packages("png", type="binary")`. There's probably not a good reason to compile from source.

Comment: In addition to @MrFlick 's solution, you could prevent the attempt to install from source (which failed for {png} in your case) by setting this option: `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")`. Then install.